# Go vanity imports, unrecognized import path, no-import meta tags

Tags: go

`go` is complaining that meta-tags don't exist, when they do.

```
➜ go version                    
go version go1.14.15 linux/amd64
```

```
➜ curl "https://go.mis.vision/mis-utils?go-get=1"
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>go.mis.vision/mis-utils</title>
<meta name="go-import" content="go.mis.vision/mis-utils  ssh://git@ssh.dev.azure.com:v3/somewhere">
<meta name="go-source" content="go.mis.vision/mis-utils _ _ _">
<style>
* { font-family: sans-serif; }
body { margin-top: 0; }
.content { display: inline-block; }
code { display: block; font-family: monospace; font-size: 1em; background-color: #d5d5d5; padding: 1em; margin-bottom: 16px; }
ul { margin-top: 16px; margin-bottom: 16px; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="content">
<h2>go.mis.vision/mis-utils</h2>
<code>go get go.mis.vision/mis-utils</code>
<code>import "go.mis.vision/mis-utils"</code>
Home: <a href="https://godoc.org/go.mis.vision/mis-utils">https://godoc.org/go.mis.vision/mis-utils</a><br/>
Source: <a href="#ZgotmplZ">ssh://git@ssh.dev.azure.com:v3/somewhere</a><br/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
➜ go get go.mis.vision/mis-utils
go: go.mis.vision/mis-utils@v1.0.1: unrecognized import path "go.mis.vision/mis-utils": parse https://go.mis.vision/mis-utils?go-get=1: no go-import meta tags ()
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

specify additional parameter for the repo in vanity config: `"VCS": "git"`

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, `vangen` was producing an invalid go-import format.

It should be: `go.mis.vision/mis-utils git ssh://git@ssh.dev.azure.com/v3/somewhere`